# Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2393)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, chatbot

I working with URL Uploader telegram. I am downloading the file using aria2 and it also downloading but it not uploading the file to telegram. when it tries to upload it to the telegram it shows me this error "Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot bot-token/sendDocument (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2393)')))"

```
import os
import subprocess
import requests
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

BOT_TOKEN = 'bot-token'
ARIA2C_EXE_PATH = 'aria2c.exe'
# DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'path_to_download_directory'

def start(update, context):
    """Handle the /start command."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi! Send me a file URL and I will download it for you.')

def download_file(url, update):
    """Download a file using Aria2."""
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.basename(url))
    # DOWNLOAD_DIR
    update.message.reply_text('Downloading started....')
    subprocess.run([ARIA2C_EXE_PATH, '-x', '16', '-o', file_path, url], check=True)
    update.message.reply_text('File downloaded successfully.')
    return file_path

def send_file(bot, chat_id, file_path):
    """Send a file to the user."""
    url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/sendDocument'
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        response = requests.post(url, data={'chat_id': chat_id}, files={'document': f}, verify=None)
        statuscode = response.raise_for_status()
        print(statuscode)


def handle_message(update, context):
    """Handle incoming messages."""
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    url = update.message.text.strip()
    if not url:
        update.message.reply_text('Please provide a valid file URL.')
        return
    try:
        file_path = download_file(url, update)
        send_file(context.bot, chat_id, file_path)
        update.message.reply_text('File sent successfully.')
    except Exception as e:
        update.message.reply_text(f'Error: {str(e)}')

def main():
    """Run the bot."""
    updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_message))
    updater.start_polling(timeout=500)
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I thought it was SSL validation error then I disable the validation process But, again it gives me the same error. I don't understand what's saying python through this error.